# How to group and sort columns by occurrence of a Letter in terms of %s and also find the mean of another column in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following pandas dataframe:

| Date | PtsMoved | Profile | Type | EventName | Indy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2010-11-19 | 16.250 | A | High Impact Expected | Fed Chairman Bernanke Speaks | 29.2500 |
| 2010-11-23 | 43.000 | NaN | High Impact Expected | Prelim GDP q/q | 29.5500 |
| 2010-11-24 | 50.500 | D | High Impact Expected | New Home Sales | 35.2000 |
| 2010-11-30 | 34.870 | NaN | High Impact Expected | CB Consumer Confidence | 31.5240 |
| 2010-12-01 | 54.500 | B | High Impact Expected | ISM Manufacturing PMI | 32.3740 |

Some rows have NAN Values for the profile column, while others contain a single letter value, and others with multiple letter values ranging from A-D. Each event under EventName has multiple occurrence throughout the dataset

What I'm trying to do is sort the table by EventName and put the occurrence of A, B, C, or D Profile with the percentages of how many times it is present under the EventName column and the average(mean) Indy value per EventName.

| EventName | Indy | Profile |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Fed Chairman Bernanke Speaks | XX.XX | A(34%), B(45%) |
| Prelim GDP q/q | XX.XX | D(14%) |

I have tried to groupby but am unsure of how to sort multiple columns by it.

Comment: I don't understand the expected output from the provided input... where are the other `EventName`? And why is `A` 34% and `B` 45% under `Fed Chairman Bernanke Speaks`

Comment: Hey @AndrejKesely, it's an example, the goal is to make it represent how often it occurs through the datasets but present it is a percentage